# Error 2013 when trying to connect with MYSQL Container

Tags: mysql, docker, mysql-workbench

I have a MYSQL container running on my machine under the command

`docker run --name=my_container -dp 3310:3310 mysql/mysql-server`

Everytime i try to connect with the container(via MYSQL Workbench or via cmd) i get an error 2013 saying

`"Lost Connection to mysql server at 'reading initial communication packet' system error : 0."`

Can someone help me out on how to make my codes or my Workbench to connect with my mysql container?

Comment: Are you sure that port is right? Usually `mysql` listens on 3306.

Comment: Yeah , thats the default , but i'm setting to my 3310 listen to 3310 in the docker

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
docker run --name=my_container -dp 3310:3306 mysql/mysql-server
```

Then you may connect to the container, see also [Docker Networking](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/)